# upload video clips display video thumb images not working? php

Tags: php

I have created an upload_video.php page and having issues with it. Hoping that some PHP genius irate: can help me out a little for which I would be ever so grateful.

Change my video page does not display video thumb images. Linked to include/generatevideothumb.php

In my upload_video.php page I have defined thumb variables as follows

```
// Thumb size
$th_max_height1 = 150;
$th_max_width1 = 250;
$th_max_width = 55;
$th_max_height = 55;
$thumb_dir="upload/video/thumbs/";
$thumb_dir1="upload/video/thumbs1/";


// Thumb
$thumb_video_name=$video_name;
generatevideothumb($dir,$th_max_width, $th_max_height,$thumb_dir,$thumb_video_name);
generatevideothumb($dir,$th_max_width1, $th_max_height1,$thumb_dir1,$thumb_video_name);
```

---

**The issue is with creating video thumb images. Error is:
Warning: imagecreate() [function.imagecreate]: Invalid image dimensions in html\include\generatevideothumb.php on line 25**

Complete code from generatevideothumb.php below

```
<?php
function generatevideothumb($im_file,$th_max_width, $th_max_height,$thumb_dir,$thumb_video_name)
{
@chmod($im_file,0777);
$image_attribs = getimagesize($im_file);

if($image_attribs[0]>$th_max_width)
{
$ratio = $th_max_width/$image_attribs[0];
$th_width = $image_attribs[0] * $ratio;
$th_height = $image_attribs[1] * $ratio;
}
elseif($image_attribs[1]>$th_max_height)
{
$ratio = $th_max_height/$image_attribs[1];
$th_width = $image_attribs[0] * $ratio;
$th_height = $image_attribs[1] * $ratio;
}
else
{
$th_width = $image_attribs[0];
$th_height = $image_attribs[1];
}
**//This code below is where I get that error saying invalid image dimensions
$im_new = imagecreate($th_width,$th_height); //returns an image identifier representing a black image of size x_size by y_size.
$th_file_name = $thumb_dir.$thumb_video_name;
@chmod($th_file_name,0777);**

if($image_attribs[2]==2)
{
$im_old = imageCreateFromJpeg($im_file);
imagecopyresized($im_new,$im_old,0,0,0,0,$th_width,$th_height, $image_attribs[0], $image_attribs[1]);
imagejpeg($im_new,$th_file_name,100);
}
elseif($image_attribs[2]==1)
{
$im_old = imagecreatefromgif($im_file);
imageCopyResampled($im_new,$im_old,0,0,0,0,$th_width,$th_height, $image_attribs[0], $image_attribs[1]);
imagegif($im_new,$th_file_name,100);
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are using wrong thumbnail dimensions. Please echo

```
<?php
    echo $th_width ."  ".$th_height; //check their values what are you getting

    //before to call following function
    $im_new = imagecreate($th_width,$th_height); 
?>
```

Comment: Hi Usman thanks tried that got echo returned as: 55 55150 150

Comment: ok, strange. try to debug it line by line check which exact function call giving you that error. Some where your dimensions are not correct for instance they might 1px 1px, 0 etc.